# Notepad++ Remove line with specific word in multiple files within a directory

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to REMOVE lines in a MULTIPLE text files with a particular word. Is this possible in Notepad++?

At the moment, I can replace those lines with a blank line. However how do I remove them in multiple files within a directory? I tried the "Mark" method whereby we can remove lines however it seems only possible for single file.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting lines with specific words in multiple files in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513477/deleting-lines-with-specific-words-in-multiple-files-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Search` > `Find in Files` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   <Brand>Acer<\/Brand>\r?\n?
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   [leave empty!]
   ```
3. Directory: select the directory with your files
4. Search mode: select radio button "Regular Expression"
5. Then press `Replace in Files` (actually press first the `Find All` to be sure that it works, and then the Replace).

Comment: Just a tip: If you are working with XMLs, copy the whole line (with spaces in the beginning)  in step 1 above. By doing this, the formatting will remain in its original state.