# Deleting lines with specific words in multiple files in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, editor

I'm trying to removing a specific line from many files I'm working on with Notepad++.

Upon searching, I found [Notepad++ Remove line with specific word in multiple files within a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369180/notepad-remove-line-with-specific-word-in-multiple-files-within-a-directory) but somehow the regex provided (`^.*(?:YOURSTRINGHERE).*\r\n$`) from the answers doesn't work for me (screenshot: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/311547963883388938/407737068475908096/unknown.png).

I read on some other questions/answers that certain regex doesn't work in newer/older Notepad++ versions. I was using Notepad++ 5.x.x then updated to the latest 7.5.4, but neither worked with the regex provided in the question above.

At the moment I can work around it by replacing that line with nothing, twice (because there are only 2 variants that I need to remove from those files) but that leaves an empty line at the end of the files. So I have to do another step further to remove that empty line.

I'm hoping someone can offer helps that allow me to remove that line and leave no empty line/space behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex you attempt to use will only match your line, if it is followed by an empty line and Windows linebreaks (CR LF) are used. This is due to `\r\n$` which matches a linebreak sequence followed by the end of the line.

Instead you might want to use

```
^.*(?:YOURSTRINGHERE).*\R?
```

To match the line containing your string and optionally a following line break sequence to remove the line instead of emptying it out. This will leave you with a trailing newline, if your word is contained in the last line of a file. You can use

```
(\R)?.*(?:YOURSTRINGHERE).*(?(1)|\R)
```

To avoid this. It uses a conditional to either match the previous linebreak, or the following if there is none.